How can I use/modify a class in different functions of another class?
I'm trying to create a game in C++, using SDL.
My structure for the game-code in the main is like this:

Create object game. (create NEEDED objects such as the SDL window or camera)

Call function start from object game. (This is where every Entity or other game components like tilemaps or ui is created)

Loop through functions gameLoop (physics) and Renderloop of object game until window closed.

Call function CleanUp of object game, SDL_Quit() and so on.


My problem is, that the different methods of class Game need objects such as TileMap or window. However, those get created in functions like start and not in the member initizer list of the constructor. They cant be created in the member init. list, because some of those objects need some variables that can only be calculated later on.
Example:
In the constructor of game the SDL window should be created. However, the function "renderLoop" of game also needs to access that SDL window.
so game.hpp basically looked like this
class Game
{
public:
    Game(); // Here created: Window, Camera, Textures
    void start();
    void gameLoop(const Uint8* p_keyBoardState);
    void RenderLoop();
    void CleanUp();
    
    const int reference_win_width = 1920;
    const int reference_win_height = 1080;
    int win_height;
    int win_width;

    /* Textures */
    SDL_Texture* Dirt_Texture;
    SDL_Texture* Test_Texture;

    /* Things needed to render */
    Camera playerCamera;
    float scalefactor;
    RenderWindow window;
    TileMap TestMap;
};

and game.cpp looked like this (shortened):
Game::Game() 
{   //Initate every necessary object
    
    win_width = 2000;
    win_height = 1000;
    float widthScaleFactor = win_width / (float)reference_win_width;
    float heightScaleFactor = win_height / (float)reference_win_height;
    
    scalefactor = 1; 
    window("TestGame", win_width, win_height, scalefactor); //doesnt work
    // std::cout << window.getRefreshRate() << std::endl;
    Dirt_Texture = window.loadTexture("res/gfx/Dirt_Texture.png");
    Test_Texture = window.loadTexture("res/gfx/Test.png");
    playerCamera(Vector2f(0,0), Vector2f(100,100)); //doesnt work
}
Game::RenderLoop()
{
    //blah blah here is much more
    window.display();
    window.clear();
}

Welp, I wish it was that simple, but 1000 error got thrown at me. I learned, that the .hpp file now doesnt know what to do with those empty classes it got (idk how to describe it better).
So I put the classes in the member init. list of the constructor like this:
Game::Game() 
: window blah blah, everything else 
{
}

However, as already metioned I need some variables (like scalefactor, temporarily set to 1) to be calculated before creating objects such as window.
My current solution is to create a pointer for each needed class in the hpp file, example:
(BTW: I created more objects, not only camera, I just wanted to keep it short)
class Game
{
public:
    Camera* playerCamera;
//blah blah
}

And then create the class on the "heap" (i just learned today that something like that exists) by using
playerCamera = new Camera(Vector2f(0,0), Vector2f(100,100));

in the cpp file.
In the cleanUp file i put
delete playerCamera;

to remove all those objects from the heap.
It works, although I heard that I should use "smart pointers" instead of raw pointers. But I also feel like there has to be a cleaner, better way to access the class.
So basically:

I need objects to be accessible from different functions (methods) of another object

I cant use the member init. list, because I need variables that get created later to be passed into the objects.

I currently use raw pointers and call the functions with "->"



"My structure for the game-code in the main is" -- is too broad for a Stack Overflow question. Focus on your specific issue, look at it abstractly, simplify, and provide an example that does not rely on your game at all. (You could provide some information about your game as context, but that would go at the end of your question, basically like a footnote,)

yes, smart pointers are a way to go, instead of storing Camera playerCamera; you should store std::unique_ptr<Camera> playerCamera;, this way you don't need to manually call delete at the end ... and you don't have to initialize it in the constructor, you can initialize it any any point so long as it is never used before it is initialized with something like playerCamera = std::make_unique<Camera>(....);

also i think you are trying to brute-force your C++ learning by trying everything until something works, i would recommend you use any good C++ book and learn C++ step by step, instead of trying to learn everything all at once and shoot yourself in the foot on every step.

"I cant use the member init. list, because I need variables that get created later to be passed into the objects." - ¿Have you considered reordering creation of your objects so you can pass required stuff to member initialization list?

Alright, thank you all for your improvements and suggestions (and fixes). I will try to keep it shorter next time.

@user7860670: See also my suggestion regarding forward declarations.

Technical comment 1: For delayed initialization, prefer optionals to pointers
Your original intent was to have plain members, within the Game object; you did not intend to switch between multiple cameras existing independently of your game; nor to perform complex lifetime management from cameras, or have arrays of cameras etc.
Given this fact, even your inelegant/not-clean solution to the object inter-dependencies problem - should not require pointers. The idiomatic way to express "This field may hold a value of type T, but may hold nothing" in modern C++ is using std::optional<T>. You may want to read this blog post by Casey Carter about it :
std::optional: How, when and why?
the way this works, in your example, is:
class Game
{
public:
    std::optional<Camera> playerCamera;
// blah blah
}

and you don't have to initialize playerCamera when constructing a Game instance; optional's default-initialize to std::nullopt, i.e. they start out as empty/having no value.
Later, you can write:
myGame.playerCamera = Camera{Vector2f{0,0}, Vector2f{100,100}};

Actual (vague) answer
The dependency problems you describe likely mean you are doing something wrong. You write:

the different ... methods... of object game need objects such as TileMap or window. However, those get created in functions like `start() and not in the member initizer list of the constructor... some of those objects need some variables that can only be calculated later on.

If a Game object cannot exist or be defined without a tile map and a window existing before it - then, probably, you should not create these objects within the Game object's methods, but before creating your Game object. Then you can initialize it at construction with what it actually needs; or alternatively, write a "named constructor idiom", e.g.:
Game makeGame( /* etc. etc. */)
{
    auto tileMap = loadTileMap(/* etc. etc. */);
    auto window = getWindow(/* etc. etc. */);
    return Game{std::move(tileMap), window};
}

Note that in my example I assumed window is a handle which can just be copied around while tileMap is a heavy object which needs to be moved rather than copied, and if Game::Game() were to take a reference to tileMap, that wouldn't be good, since tileMap goes out of scope when returning from makeGame().
Alternatively, if the tile map or window can only be created after some other computational activity of a Game object, then, indeed, these can be made into optional fields of Game.
In both cases, a non-ctor method Game::doFoo() should not care about object initialization. If doFoo() uses, say, a tileMap - then either it takes the tile map as a parameter, or it uses member - and that member can be constructed/initialized at any time before doFoo() is called, not necessearily on construction of Game.
You also write:

I learned, that the .hpp file now doesnt know what to do with those empty classes it got (idk how to describe it better).

Perhaps you mean to say, that the errors are actually due to the compiler requiring the definition of classes which have not yet been defined? And that there is no order of definition which avoids this?
If that is the case, then you need to avail yourself of forward declarations. For example, perhaps Game.h is:
class TileMap;
class Camera;

class Game {
public:
  void doFoo();
  Game(Camera & camera, TileMap const& testTileMap) 
      : playerCamera(camera), testMap(testTileMap)
  {
      /* more code here, which doesn't use TileMap nor Camera */
  }

private:
    Camera& playerCamera;
    TileMap const & testMap;

This will work even if the TileMap and Camera are undefined - e.g. if you've not yet included Camera.h and TileMap.h. Note that the use of a non-const reference means that the lifetime of a playerCamera in my example, managed elsewhere, must exceed the lifetime of Game instances which use that camera.
You can also write a class that only gets/creates a camera after construction; but some of the function implementations will probably need to be relegated to a .cpp file, or somewhere else where the header files for all relevant classes have already been included.
